# How can I add CSS style in nuxt-i18n?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I have a following translation:

`en.js`

```js
test: {
  hello: 'My name is Ben'
}
```

If I want to let 'name' is blue word,other word is black.

I have tried following code:
`en.js`

```js
test: {
  hello: 'My <span style="color:blue">name<span> is Ben'
}
```

But it will show
`My <span style="color:blue">name<span> is Ben`

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have *code* in your i18n JSON (just text), rather use a conditional like this in your template

```html
<div :class="$i18n.locale === 'en' ? 'color-blue' : 'color-red'">{{ $t('hello') }}</div>
```